# chrome css cascade

Tags: css, google-chrome, overriding

I have an element that is styled twice in my css for property color. The more specific selector gives color: red, the other color: black. In the actual displayed result black is shown.

When I inspect the element and look a the computed style I see that the line that gives color black is striked out and red is not striked out. However also there, the resulting color is shown to be black, event though the respective line is striked out.

When I use !important it still looks exactly the same. Anybody have an idea why that might be?

Comment: Can you post a simple test case on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: maybe its showing that color for a parent element?

Comment: the problem is that i cannot reproduce the problem with a small example..

Comment: Then post the smallest example you can.

Answer (score -1):

CSS is a cascading style sheet so it applies the last code of your element.

```
 <p>TEST</p>
 p{color:red;!important}
 p{color:blue;}
```

So color of p element will be blue. It's a normal behaviour of css.

But CSS gives priority on different selectors.

Live prototype of your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2YMD3/2/

You can check css priority on [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/Priority_level_of_selector)

Comment: Not sure if that misplaced `!important` is deliberate. This answer is a mess and I can't connect any dots on it.